# A lot of buffers are being dropped

Tags: webcam, cheese

```
(cheese:6560): cheese-WARNING **: A lot of buffers are being dropped.: gstbasesink.c(2854): gst_base_sink_is_too_late (): /GstCameraBin:camerabin/GstViewfinderBin:vf-bin/ClutterGstVideoSink:cluttergstvideosink0:
There may be a timestamping problem, or this computer is too slow.
```

Why while using cheese package for my cam this message on the terminal
What makes computer slow or timestamping problem

OS: ubuntu 16.04

Fairly new to ubuntu

Comment: Did you find a solution?